# How to set up cometD work with Salesforce?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-community, cometd, event-notification-service

I need help! I am using new community template and I need to show notifications. Community licenses don't support Streaming API, therefor empApi doesn't work. I have to use cometD

I am trying to use cometD with my platform event, but get the next error

sampleNotificationLWC.js:4 Error in handshaking:

```
{"id":"6","successful":false,"channel":"/meta/handshake","failure":{"exception":{},"connectionType":"long-polling","message":{"id":"6","version":"1.0","minimumVersion":"1.0","channel":"/meta/handshake","supportedConnectionTypes":["long-polling","callback-polling"],"advice":{"timeout":60000,"interval":0}}}}
```

And

TypeError: Cannot read property '_debug' of undefined...

My code:

**SampleNotificationLWC.js**

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire, api } from 'lwc';

import { loadScript } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";

import cometd from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/cometd";

import getSessionId from '@salesforce/apex/CometD_Controller.getSessionId';

export default class SampleNotificationLWC extends LightningElement {

    @api channel;

    libInitialized = false;
    @track sessionId;
    @track error;

    @wire(getSessionId)
    wiredSessionId({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.sessionId = data;
            this.error = undefined;
            loadScript(this, cometd)
            .then(() => {
                this.initializecometd()
            });
        } else if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            this.error = error;
            this.sessionId = undefined;
        }
    }

    initializecometd() {
        if (this.libInitialized) {
            return;
        }
        this.libInitialized = true;
        var lwcThisContext = this;
        var cometdlib = new window.org.cometd.CometD();
        cometdlib.configure({
            url: window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + '/cometd/52.0',
            requestHeaders: { Authorization: 'OAuth ' + this.sessionId},
            appendMessageTypeToURL : false,
            logLevel: 'debug'
        });
        cometdlib.websocketEnabled = false;
        cometdlib.handshake(function(status) {
            console.log('Channel Name  ', lwcThisContext.channel);
            if (status.successful) {
                cometdlib.subscribe('/event/'+ lwcThisContext.channel, function(message){
                    const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('message', { detail: message });
                    lwcThisContext.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
                });
            } else {
                console.error('Error in handshaking: ' + JSON.stringify(status));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**SampleNotificationLWC.html**

```
<template>
    
</template>
```

**SampleCometD.js**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class SampleCometD extends LightningElement {

    messageReceived(event) {
        const message = event.detail;
        console.log(message);

    }
}
```

**SampleCometD.html**

```
<template>
    <c-sample-notification-l-w-c channel="My_Event__e" onmessage={messageReceived}></c-sample-notification-l-w-c>
</template>
```

**CometD_Controller.cls**

```
public with sharing class CometD_Controller {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
        public static String getSessionId() {
        return UserInfo.getSessionId();
    }
}
```

Where am I wrong? I am using cometD.js 3.1.1 as a static resource

Comment: Would you be able to show the Chrome Developer Console error you are seeing when trying to use the empApi component?

Comment: Community licenses don't support Streaming API, therefor empApi doesn't work. I am looking for a solution to display notifications on the community pages. I does not know another solution except cometD.

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this ?